# Database Mirroring of SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, mirroring

I have two databases that are mirrored to another server using database mirroring.

The mirror server has to be down for some reason for few days.

Now, the production server is having principal databases in `(PRINCIPAL/DISCONNECTED)` State.

Clients can access those databases.

Questions

- So what happens when they keep on adding data to these databases??
- Will the data get committed or waits till the mirror comes up?

Answer (score 2):

Your `.LDF` log is growing, as it cannot be truncated because the mirror is unavailable. Eventually you'll run out of space unless you either break the mirroring or bring the mirror back online.

Comment: Absolutely correct, you need to remove the mirroring and re-initialize the mirror copy when the server becomes available again.

Answer (score 1):

The transactions will be committed on the principle. When the mirror is up again, it will take more time to synchronize.

Comment: This is a valid option if the mirror is down for a small amount of time, but spanning days on a busy database is probably a bad idea.